Horror movie in which one or more characters peer through windows at a house across the way and watch the silhouette of a man who might be dead
Viewed at US drive-in mid 1980's, this horror movie could (??) have been non-English and black & white. Unknown release date. Unknown country of origin.
Passage of time has made me an unreliable narrator. Here goes:
It is nightfall. One or more characters are inside a house and they are peering through windows at a house across the way. They watch the silhouette of a man moving slowly, floor by floor. Ominous music. The man might be dead.
There might have been a burial or a scene of a burial crypt.
Can't remember plot. And I think it started raining during the viewing = reduced screen visibility.

I have found my answer: 'Zeder' (1983) 98 min. Italian horror flick directed by Pupi Avati. An edited version, aka, 'Revenge of the  Dead' was released in U.S.
I used a movie vault website to retrieve all Italian horror releases from 1980-1985. Then I read through synopses until I struck gold. Time-consuming but satisfying.

Hi, it's great that you found it!  To improve your answer you might want to include a synopsis of the movie, and maybe a matching screenshot.

Sounds like 'Fright Night' from 1985.  It's a horror movie, shot in color, about a suburban teenager who discovers a vampire has moved in next door.
In the first 20 minutes, the teen watches through his window as the vampire kills victims in his house, moves a coffin into the basement, and the vampire's minion disposes of corpses in the middle of the night, all set to ominous music. Of course, no one believes the teen.
It's an American movie but features British actor Roddy McDowall.
It's an underrated classic, streaming now on HBO Max.

No, this isn't it. I've seen Fright Night many times. You're right; it's underrated. Thanks.

Not sure if you're still searching for the film but, I'm pretty sure it's Nosferatu (1922).
Count Orlock is a vampire, ergo a man who is (un)dead. In the scene provided, Ellen opens her window to see the dead man peering out at her, followed by her friend Harding rushing in to help.
As a black and white German silent film, it fits with your description. The burial crypt you recall, may be when main character Thomas Hutter discovers Count Orlock's tomb.
Can't believe nobody suggested it until now.




Thank you, but no it isn't Nosferatu. Great old flick, btw.

You sure it was a horror movie? It sounds a lot like a Sherlock Holmes film "The Empty House".
Holmes has resurfaced after having escaped death at the Reichenbach Falls, but is pursued by a disciple of the late Professor Moriarty who is aware of his survival. The latter, still loyal to his old boss, tries to assassinate Holmes. From a house opposite 221b Baker Street, he shoots at what he takes to be Holmes, but is in fact only a bust of him, being moved about by Holmes' housekeeper to make it seem alive. As he fires, Holmes and Watson burst in and seize him.Iirc the film was in black and white.

No.I've seen the SH film you've referenced and it isn't what I'm searching for. Thank you
